# A* algorithm implementation node-parent bug

Tags: python, a-star

I have a problem with my attempt at A* - this does not happen every time it runs, but every so often it makes it so two cells become each other's parents.
This in turn leads to an infinite loop when I try to recreate the path. I've been trying to find out why this happens for some time now, but can't figure it out, so any help would be appreciated.

```
def find_path(self, start, end):
    tstart = time.time()
    count = 0
    evaled = set()
    notEvaled = set([start])
    start.g_score(start)
    start.h_score(end)
    start.f_score()

    while len(notEvaled) != 0:
        current = min(notEvaled, key=attrgetter('f'))     
        notEvaled.remove(current)

        for neighbour in current.neighbours:
            if neighbour.full or neighbour in evaled: continue
            if neighbour in notEvaled:
                if neighbour.parent != None and neighbour.parent.g > current.g:
                    neighbour.parent = current
                    neighbour.g_score(start)
                    neighbour.f_score()
            else:

                neighbour.parent = current

                neighbour.g_score(start)
                neighbour.h_score(end)
                neighbour.f_score()
                notEvaled.add(neighbour)

                if neighbour == end:
                    path = []
                    while end != None:
                        path.insert(0, end)
                        end = end.parent
                    return path

            evaled.add(current)

    return None
```

Here are my score function, but i doubt they matter

```
def g_score(self, start):
    if self == start:
        self.g = 0
    else:
        self.g = self.parent.g + 1

def h_score(self, end):
    self.h = abs(end.x - self.x) + abs(end.y - self.y)

def f_score(self):
    self.f = self.g + self.h
```

Comment: What does `neighbor.full` do?

Answer (score 0):

Before I begin: the common naming convention is `openSet`/`closedSet` instead of `evaled`/`notEvaled`. The naming convention you use becomes confusing when you need to use a double negative, as in: `aNode not in notEvaled`. So, in my answer I use the `openSet`/`closedSet` convension.

One thing that stands out to me is you add the `current` node to the `closedSet` (`evaled`) immediately after removing it from the `openSet` (`notEvaled`).

The second thing that stands out is that you check whether a node is the endpoint before adding it to the `openSet`. While this may seem like an optimization, it actually forces you to perform the check on every single opened node, rather than on the subset of open nodes that are actually visited.

Here is an adaptation of your A* algorithm that should work as expected. It is based on the [pseudo code from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode) except that it integrates the `reconstruct_path` method:

```
def find_path(self, start, end):
    tstart = time.time()
    count = 0
    closedSet = set()
    openSet = set([start])
    start.g_score(start)
    start.h_score(end)
    start.f_score()

    while len(openSet) != 0:
        current = min(openSet, key=attrgetter('f'))     
        openSet.remove(current)
        closedSet.add(current)

        #Check if goal is reached
        if(current == end):
            #Construct path from start to goal
            path = []
            while end != None:
                path.insert(0,end)
                end = end.parent
                return path

        #Open neighbors
        for neighbour in current.neighbours:
            if neighbour.full: continue 
            if neighbour in closedSet: continue

            tentative_g_score = 1 + current.g

            if neighbour not in openSet or tentative_g_score < neighbor.g:
                neighbour.parent = current
                neighbour.g = tentative_g_score
                neighbour.f_score()
                if neighbour not in openSet:
                    openSet.add(neighbour)

    return None
```